# What's a good way to handle unitialized private members in Scala objects?

Tags: scala, oop

It seems like having uninitialized members in the object body is forbidden in Scala objects..
I wanted to do something like (if it was in Java)

```
class MyClass {
  private String str;

  private String reassignString(String value) {
     str = value;
  }
```

I'm restricted on changing this code from object to class (since this repo is used by many teams) - what's a good Scala way to handle this kind of situation? Sorry the question is really vague.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another bad idea:

```
object Lazy {
  lazy val v = if (underlying ne null) underlying else ???
  var underlying: String = null
}
Try(Lazy.v)
Lazy.underlying = "yes"
Try(Lazy.v)
Lazy.underlying = null
Try(Lazy.v)
```

The point is that the lazy val gets more than one shot at initialization, but is successfully initialized only once, if that's what you want.

Note that default initializer syntax is on its way out. They want you to write `null` if you want `null`.

My preferred default initializer:

```
var underlying: String = underlying
```

just to break the ice at dinner parties.

Answer (score 1):

Uninitalized values are a bad idea, so `str` needs to be initialised to a valid value.

There are three obvious options:

Give `str` the default value

```
private var str: String = _
```

Pick you own default

```
private var str: String = "undefined"
```

Use `Option`

```
class MyClass {
  private var str: Option[String] = None

  private def reassignString(value: String): Unit = {
    str = Some(value)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`str` in this Java code [*is* initialized, to `null`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5). Scala simply requires you to make it explicit whether that's what you want.